# How to get awaitable Thread.Sleep?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

I'm writing a network-bound application based on await/sleep paradigm.

Sometimes, connection errors happen, and in my experience it pays to wait for some time and then retry operation again.

The problem is that if I use Thread.Sleep or another similar blocking operation in await/async, it blocks all activity in the caller thread.

What should I replace Thread.Sleep(10000) with to achieve the same effect as

```
await Thread.SleepAsync(10000)
```

?

**UPDATE**

I'll prefer an answer which does this without creating any additional thread

Answer (score 465, accepted):

The other answers suggesting starting a new thread are a bad idea - there's no need to do that at all. Part of the point of `async`/`await` is to *reduce* the number of threads your application needs.

You should instead use [`Task.Delay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay.aspx) which *doesn't* require a new thread, and was designed precisely for this purpose:

```
// Execution of the async method will continue one second later, but without
// blocking.
await Task.Delay(1000);
```

This solution also has the advantage of [allowing cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-task-delay(system-int32-system-threading-cancellationtoken)), if a cancellation token is provided. Example:

```
public async Task DoWork(CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000, token);
}
```

Comment: I'm still coming to grips with the a4.5 stuff. Where's the branch of execution on the code after that statement? Does the non-sleeping/blocking portion execute it or the 'thread' that waits? Does the main non-blocking execution just leave the block following (aka return)?

Comment: @kenny: You may find my [`async` intro](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful. When the awaitable returned by `Task.Delay` is `await`ed, since it's not complete, the current method returns an incomplete task. Later, when the `Delay` completes (off a timer, not a thread), the remainder of the method is scheduled to run. The continuation runs in a "context" which *may* return to the same original thread - details on my blog.

Comment: @StephenCleary thanks for that. So am I right in saying that the code after await is 'scheduled' for execution and the calling thread returns?

Comment: Yes, the calling thread returns (immediately) and the code after the `await` is scheduled (eventually).