# Change button color for a short period of time from its last click c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, click, background-color

I used this link in order to solve my problem, but with a partial success
[Change button color for a short time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105792/change-button-color-for-a-short-time)

I need to Present a red button.
Whenever the button is clicked, it changes its color to green for a period of 5 second,
Consecutive clicks should be supported but should not accumulate i.e. the button color should turn back to red 5 second  **after the last click**.

**my code:**

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Timer timer = new Timer { Interval = 5000 };
    timer.Elapsed += HandleTimerTick;
    myButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen);
    timer.Start();
}

private void HandleTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer timer = (Timer)sender;
    timer.Stop();
    myButton.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
    {
        myButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    });          
}
```

it works but just **5 seconds from my first click** and the timer not resets every time I've click the button.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: since you are using wpf have you considered animations ?

Comment: I've tried your code and it works as intended on my end. Is this all of your relevant code?

Comment: @ZSH I'm still new in WPF and don't know how to use animations yet

Comment: @MilenPavlov Yes this is all my relevant code. when I'm clicking the button once, and after 4 seconds click it again - it still become Red after 1 second (from my first click), and not resets the timer to a new 5 seconds.

Comment: @Orionlk i see that you got an answer but still i recommend checking out WPF Animations, any Google search will do

Comment: @ZSH Thank you, I will check that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the timer out of the event and restart it every time the user clicks. Something along these lines:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Timer timer;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer = new Timer{Interval = 5000};
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {               
            timer.Elapsed += HandleTimerTick;
            myButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen);
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void HandleTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer timer = (Timer)sender;
            timer.Stop();
            myButton.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
            {
                myButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            });
        }
    }
```