# await still blocks current UI thread

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I tried to use the following code to run some task in thread pool:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await test().ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
}
private Task test()
{
   Thread.Sleep(100000);
   return null;
}
```

The code is supposed to run in the threadpool, however the current UI thread is still being blocked.

So can anyone help to take a look?
thanks,

Comment: Using `async` / `await` does not mean that your task will run on a different thread.

Comment: but should "continueOnCapturedContext: false" make it run in thread pool?

Comment: No, `continueOnCapturedContext: false` will ensure that the continuation of an `await` is not invoked using the `SynchronizationContext` and instead finishes in `ThreadPool`. In your question your `Thread.Sleep()` is simply executed on the same thread that invoked the `test()` method, therefore it blocks. The code will run synchronously until it comes to the first `await`. So `test()` is invoked synchronously, the result (a `null` `Task`) is "awaited".

Comment: Is your Test() method is `synchronized` or do it have `async` invocation ?

Comment: if its synchronized you could try using `await Task.Run(() =>Test());`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18015586/1876572

Comment: Your code is returning `null` instead of a `Task` that represents the asynchronous operation!

Answer (score 5):

> The code is supposed to run in the threadpool

No, that is not at all true. `async` does not run your code on a thread pool thread.

I suggest you read my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), which explains what `async` *does* do, and the [official `async` FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx), which addresses the thread pool misconception specifically:

> Does the “async” keyword cause the invocation of a method to queue to the ThreadPool? To create a new thread? To launch a rocket ship to Mars?
>
> No. No. And no.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Task.Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await test();
}

private Task test()
{
    return Task.Delay(100000);
}
```

### Edit :

[Related question / answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429707/how-to-get-awaitable-thread-sleep)